# nerdtree and current directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

How can I achieve this situation?

1. Open vim in my home folder.
2. Navigate somewhere with NERDTree
3. Run the `:!ls` command and see the contents of the directory in that NERDTree is displaying

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `:help NERDTreeChDirMode`. Setting it to `2` will do what you want.

Comment: i got it thanks! but to be complete (i'm not a vim guru) the answer will include also  ":helptags ~/.vim/doc" to get docs aviable and "let g:NERDTreeChDirMode=2" in .vimrc